# Can you send a token and get ether back?

Tags: solidity, tokens

If a user sends a token, let's call it `ABC`, to the contract that issued that token, can the contract send back ether to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example:

```
contract ABCToken {
    function sell(uint abcAmount) public {
        uint ethAmount = myFunc(abcAmount);
        msg.sender.transfer(ethAmount);
    }
}
```

Of course, you probably want to make sure that this user (`msg.sender`) owns the specified amount of ABC tokens...

Answer (score 1):

Adding to goodVibration's answer, you want to make sure the user actually sent what they say they sent.

```
contract ABCToken {
    function sell(uint abcAmount) public {
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), abcAmount)); 
        uint ethAmount = myFunc(abcAmount);
        msg.sender.transfer(ethAmount);
    }
}
```

Transfer from requires the sender to first send an `approve()` to the token contract to set an allowance the above function can use to retrieve the user's tokens. The 2-step process is usually coordinated client-side or in another contract.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Risk of scribbling it up freestyle. Fixed.